# Tika doesnt output document contents

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract only the text from a pdf file using Tika by following the tutorial on their website, but i'm just getting 25k lines of text back that looks like this.

> %PDF-1.5
>   %µµµµ
>   1 0 obj
>   <>>>
>   endobj
>   2 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   3 0 obj
>   <>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   xœ•Wßoâ8?~Gâ˜Çät?Û±óCª"QÚ®î´+?t¼­öÁ‚@£Mi?ÙëíóÙ??mºœ*ˆ=žùfæóÌ„Òô/º¹™~™ÿqGrúÙm7?UÛÉ§Û¸,éönN·‹ñhú H)!
>   -Öã‘"ÉŠt¡D–Q&?‘æ´x??$mðõi<ú?-â‰‰\l£}<ÑÑ÷ø?-þ??î?
>   ˆ?F¢´0ê?ãkDƒºFä?ºjHWK‘Øa\?é1?Ld†t.lnHŠ‚¿wÕx´þm<¢û/s¢3ŽÔ?GGÏ2?ÒRZ¤Bë?+}÷o`õµ°¹?Ù{    ½AL®EL?‘˜k?Í¯?3-¤6”Z+ŠãýL’HÄiXÐßq?½Ä&ªø¹Œ'6ª!^ÇJ‡•—¡hÚXÉ zæÝvà–•É„ê;ü0?;\àú??ïò1š+#àßH©?¤ÊÒÒòR&R?³r’ÜHeg¥Ü±H†#©ýÚ ·?V0†ffË”?ê??àÀ¨ÌY4Ï?dvWN`pka€Ó?§* ¥?þ?±R?b/ùîYi?±Z/.Ur?ß™YÂH>eD?îX÷”Bboùã½K™?ø=Y#c¾??u8>¡#Dï?¢ìÈ:û8øš?Â–?ç™dç‰??±d%ó–Ð?=e¿¦§?É;%h“Bäi¯??çcW®º@S?ÝGn4÷?ú¨Þr#m¸÷¨Åö5Î¹µ¸Ûè¥q±2ÑOH«Ýž0®?:rO¯Ü¸UÓ?šÑíƒ!?+Š³`ýÂ»¶Ž•
>   Û-oiýÌ^väh_o7ŒÐT8÷~’Î

I also get the same sort of thing when trying it with .docx format too,but it works fine with .txt. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);

      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("fake.pdf"));
      ParseContext pcontext=new ParseContext();

      //Text document parser
      TXTParser  TexTParser = new TXTParser();

      TexTParser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata,pcontext);
      System.out.println("Contents of the document:" + handler.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

The problems seems to be that you are trying to use a `TXTParser` to parse a PDF document. `PDF` stands for `Portable Document Format` which includes binary data in the file.

Fortunately `Apache Tika` comes with a wrapper that will automatically detect the format of the file you are trying to parse.

Try this example from the [Tika Documentation](https://tika.apache.org/1.12/examples.html):

```
public String parseExample() throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    try (InputStream stream = ParsingExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.pdf")) {
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
        return handler.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised i was using TXTParser instead of AutoDetectParser. Can someone close or delete this question please?